# Typescript create uber-strict types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, strict

If I create a custom type such as:

```
type LowercaseString = string
```

And then use it in a function like this:

```
function displayLowercaseString(input: LowercaseString) {
  ...
}

displayLowercaseString('UPPERCASE')
```

The above example compiles perfectly and runs, since `'UPPERCASE'` is of type `string` and so is `LowercaseString`

My question is, is it possible to have a TS error such as
`type string does not match LowercaseString`
so that I am forced to put every string through a function like this before using it in `displayLowercaseString`:

```
function stringToLowercase(input: string): LowercaseString {
  return input.toLowercase as LowercaseString
}
```

Comment: What you're looking for is essentially https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160, which has been open for years and is not likely to be resolved anytime soon.

Comment: By using a string in my example I think I have created a misleading question. I don't want any kind of validation of the content of the strings. I effectively just want type names to be matched.

`type ID = number` is another example, where I wouldn't want a function that accepts type `ID` to just accept any number. It should only accept variables with the type `ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a branded type :

```
type LowercaseString = string & { __brand: 'lower' };


function stringToLowercase(input: string): LowercaseString {
  return input.toLowerCase() as LowercaseString
}

function displayLowercaseString(input: LowercaseString) {
}

const uppercaseString = 'UPPERCASE';
displayLowercaseString(uppercaseString) // nope 
displayLowercaseString(stringToLowercase(uppercaseString)) // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gdwgJwMYEMDOEDKxkCWAdgOZQC8Um%20xZAZFAN5QD6LARsukQCYBcUAOQAbRCkFQAvgG4AUPIBmAVyKpgBOESo1SAFTjwkaLBAAUxMEuADqhUgEoBhlBmx47ZRrKhRkEYErIWhZWAHTABmLIAMImpvZQWLBRrrg6JLKSiipqGlo8BJhgwuggzsZu6eZEltbJRqnutAleWbKomtRQSmCQFWkeFEIAqgAKowCiAErRAII4E4JyBUUlZSkmTaSmPX2N6QkA9IdQRHCQULIrxaXl%20x6mtrT6d3G7LpsHRydwANZAA)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for and works perfectly!

Am I correct in assuming that this does not add any additional code when compiled to JavaScript? (as with normal TS types)

Comment: @StanFlint Yes, this is purely typechecking code. You can look at the generated code in the playground !